# How to open network stream that requires a Cookie with a JWT inside using VLC

Tags: vlc-media-player

I am trying to open a network stream in VLC. However, in order to access the stream I need to provide the server with an authorization cookie containing my session token stored as a [JWT token](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON_Web_Token). How can I pass that cookie when opening a network stream in VLC?

Comment: When you say “Cookie” I assume you have username/password credentials to access that stream outside of VLC, right?

Comment: @Giacomo1968 No. The static files, including videos are protected by a middleware that checks for a JWT inside of the token cookie.

Comment: A [JWT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON_Web_Token) token is in the cookie? I doubt you can do this. You would need to know how the JWT is structured and then write a script to generate the JWT on each access. That is a complex cookie that is built on a timestamp. Meaning the cookie changes each second and each access. Very secure and not easily replicated unless you know the logic behind it and have the server access token used by the JWT token.

Comment: Any video link for test?

Comment: What's wrong with using this Firefox addon, https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/open-in-vlc/ ? It opens the stream link directly in vlc.

Comment: I think you all misunderstand his question. Some streams require you to send a cookie (e.g. amazon cloudfront policies and signatures or similar) both to get the m3u8 playlist and also to access the video content itself. You can tinker with the URL (the data can often be passed via query string as well), but this won't make VLC use it for the video data requests, hence the need to actually have VLC send these data via cookies...